# Left join resulting duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table

```
GLId        Id          DonarId
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           2          1
4           2          2
5           3          1
6           3          2
7           4          1
8           4          2
9           5          1
10          5          2
```

Now, I want to find those id's which are not present in donarId column and and whose count(donarid) is less than 8

I have written a query

```
SELECT g.id 
FROM   gamestar g 
       LEFT JOIN gamestar gs 
              ON g.id = gs.donarid 
GROUP  BY g.id, 
          g.glid 
HAVING Count(gs.donarid) < 8 
ORDER  BY g.glid
```

but it results the duplicate values.

result look like

```
ID
-----------
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

and so on.

Waiting for kind help.Thanks

Comment: If you decide to stick to your query, try using subqueries to remove the duplicates like select distinct g.id from (*your query without distinct*) g

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.id 
FROM   gamestar g 
       LEFT JOIN gamestar gs 
              ON g.id = gs.donarid 
GROUP  BY g.id, 
          g.glid 
HAVING Count(gs.donarid) < 8 
ORDER  BY g.glid
```

Comment: If I use Distinct, I need to add g.glid in Select list and result get duplicated values again

Comment: @Jayant, why to add g.glid column?

Comment: If I run your query , error :ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.,

and I want the id in order by glid

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for ids that appear fewer than 8 times are are no in the donar id column.

```
select g.id
from gamestar g
where g.donarid not in (select donarid from gamestar)
group by g.id
having count(*) < 8
```

Comment: Both queries returns same id whose count < 8, but I also need those Id which are not in donar colum

Comment: @JayantBramhankar . . . Your question does not actually make sense because you say " id's which are not present in donarId column and and whose count(donarid) is less than 8."  That is really all ids not present in the donarid column.  I think you mean "count(id) is less than 8".

Comment: Sir, output must be 1,2,3,4,5 
1 because count(1)<8 and 2,3,4,5 because they are not in donar column. The query i have specified produces the expected result , but with duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT g.id 
 FROM   gamestar g 
    LEFT JOIN gamestar gs 
          ON g.id = gs.donarid 
 GROUP  BY g.id 
 HAVING Count(gs.donarid) < 8
```

[SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b88bc/12)

Comment: Exactly, but i want the result order by glid, and if we use order by we need to use glid in group by (says sql) and results the duplicate values.

Comment: id to glid is not one to one relationship, so you cannot avoid duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT g.glid, g.id,
         COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY gs.donarid, g.glid) AS cn 
  FROM gamestar g LEFT JOIN gamestar gs ON g.id = gs.donarid
  )
  SELECT Id
  FROM cte
  WHERE cn < 8
  GROUP BY Id
```